# wkhtmltopdf how to set caching of html footer and header?

Tags: limit, wkhtmltopdf

Testing wkhtmltopdf for generating huge pdf reports.
Finaly pdf is about 600 pages. After ~500 pages got the same error

```
Error:failed to load file .......... with network status code 201 and http status code 0 - Error opening kn_footer.html: Too many open files
```

The value of fs.file-max was about 1.6M. After error I was increased it to 2097152 but it does not help.

Trying to add file cacheing but it's not working. Command line looks like:

```
wkhtmltopdf --cache-dir /tmp/ --allow /path/to/my/dir/ --margin-top 20 --load-error-handling ignore --orientation landscape --page-size A4 page kn_utf.html --footer-html kn_footer.html --header-html kn_header.html --footer-spacing 1 kn.pdf
```

Is there any way to say wkhtmltopdf get header and footer at once or close that files after each iteration?

Answer (score 0):

I too was unable to get any sort of caching to work on a 532 page document.  I did achieve some success by converting my `footer.html` file into `wkhtmltopdf` footer text.  You might also consider splitting it into two documents, run `wkhtmltodpf` twice, and then use `pdfunite` to merge the two temporary PDFs into the final document.  If you're interested in the text footer approach, here's the set of options I used.  Don't forget to set the bottom margin (`-B` option), otherwise the text footer will get dropped off the page.

```
wkhtmltopdf \
-O landscape \
-s letter \
-L 20 \
-R 20 \
-T 20 \
-B 20 \
--exclude-from-outline \
--image-dpi 300 \
--header-html $BASE_DIR/header.html \
--footer-line \
--footer-spacing  10 \
--footer-left "$FOOTER_LEFT" \
--footer-center "$FOOTER_CENTER" \
--footer-right "$FOOTER_RIGHT" \
--footer-font-size 10 \
--cache-dir $BASE_DIR/cache \
--user-style-sheet $BASE_DIR/some.css \
$TARGET_DIR/[im]*.html \
$TARGET_DIR/final.pdf
```